# how to return Retrofit response?

Tags: android, mvp, retrofit2

I would like to get movie data from server using retrofit2 in a presenter layer and setup gridview adapter in MainActivity(cause presenter should not know about context ?). However, it does not allow me to return anything from callback.
should I make another callback to retrieve  MovieDataContainer or is there better way to solve this problem

I am new to mvp so if my knowledge of mvp is wrong please point out!

```
  movieCall.enqueue(new Callback<MovieDataContainer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieDataContainer> call, Response<MovieDataContainer> response) {
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    MovieDataContainer movieDataContainer = response.body();
                    Log.d("MainPresenterImpl",movieDataContainer.toString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: you have to convert that into string and operate on that.... toString() will not work.. You have use Gson Converter or any other convert to convert

Comment: By default there is Gson Converter

Comment: No, that code works including toString(). Just dont know how to return movieDataContainer object to mainactivity

Comment: you should make an interface returning the `MovieDataContainer`

Comment: yes thats one solution. But I want to know whats best practice to set adapter in mvp using retrofit 2